# QT Application crashes trying to send a message from a client app to a server app with QCopChannel

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to send a message from a client app to a server app with `QCopChannel` in QT, but at the moment of launch the SLOT method, the application has a crash.

Code in server app:

```
MainWindow.cpp:

(...)
qcopreceiver = new QCopChannel("MYCHANNEL",this);
qcopreceiver->flush();
bool isRegistered = qcopreceiver->isRegistered("MYCHANNEL");
QDebug() << "Is registered? : " << isRegistered;
QObject::connect(qcopreceiver, SIGNAL(received(const QString &, const QByteArray &)),this, SLOT(receive(const QString &, const QByteArray &)));
(...)

void MainWindow::receive(const QString &message, const QByteArray &data)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    qDebug() << "Message received: " << message;
}
```

Code in client app:

```
void ClientClass::sendMessageToServer()
{
    QCopChannel::send ("MYCHANNEL", "receive(const QString &, const QByteArray &)", data);
}
```

When the method `sendMessageToServer()` is invoked, the application crashes and I don't know why. The log that I use to know if the channel is registered, shows that the channel is properly registered. I think that it can be a problem with qCop in a qws application but I don't have enough info in the web. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What´s `data`? Is `data` initialized properly before `sendMessageToServer()` is invoked?

Comment: Yes, data is a QByteArray properly initialized.